# Why don't static variables work as expected in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, garbage-collection

I built an ASP.NET application and a `public static` variable in it:

```
public static WebEndPointFlow[] EndPoints = new WebEndPointFlow[10];
```

where `WebEndPointFlow` is a my custom class.
The problem is: when I set some element of the array of `EndPoints`, it only can last for a very short time period. After minutes, the element becomes `null`.
I don't know what happens to my elements in the array. So I create a deathless thread to access these elements regularly, hoping GC won't process them. How pathetic, it does not work.
Any idea on how to remain my original elements always? Very appreciate!

======================================

So the problem does not matter with GC? I agree.
But why my elements become null?

===========================

One more question: does this array look the same when different users access it?

code of Class:

```
public class WebEndPointFlow
    {
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WebEndPointFlow));

    private InstantMessagingFlow flow;

    public InstantMessagingFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
    private UserEndpointSettings userEndpointSettings;
    private UserEndpoint endPoint;

    public UserEndpoint EndPoint
    {
        get { return endPoint; }
        set { endPoint = value; }
    }

    public StringBuilder Transcript { get; set; }

    private WebSocketServer wsServer;
    private Conversation conversation;

    // position in the array of 'endPoints'
    private int position;
    public int Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }
    private FailureResponseException e = null;
    private string _TargetLyncUser;
    public string TargetLyncUser
    {
        get { return _TargetLyncUser; }
        set { _TargetLyncUser = value; }
    }
    private bool sendTrans = false;
    public int Duration
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public WebEndPointFlow()
    {
    }
```

Comment: If you can access a variable then by definition it is not garbage. Your belief that the GC is clearing your variable is false. Either something else is clearing your variable, or you are accessing a *completely different variable*.

Comment: Blaming GC for removing elements from a static array is not the best way to phrase a question. I'd recommend watching for app restarts as  starting point of investigation...

Comment: @EricLippert No I'm not sure what happened. I just what to keep my element value. but how?

Comment: GC wont clear anything which is **accessible** in any part of your application. You don't need to access it for making the variable safe from GC.

Comment: Start by correctly deducing an explanation for the observed behaviour. Your explanation about the GC is almost certainly false. Come up with a different hypothesis and a way to test it.

Comment: Where do you declare `EndPoints`?

Comment: @Alexander In a standalone class. Does that matter?

Comment: @bansi Ok thank you. I just want to figure out why an existing element becoming null. I'm confused.

Comment: It seems to me that the end points are only alive for the duration of the time being taken to process the response? Is it possible the piece of code where this static variable is declared gets executed once per call whenever a response needs to be served up to the caller?

Comment: I bet the application domain is shut down every few minutes, hence why you lose your static variables.

Comment: @VictorVictis wow that's weird and horrible. if true, what I should do to solve it?

Comment: Could you show the code of class "WebEndPointFlow"?  You believe the code is perfect and GC works as devil, but other person except you can not sure that without examining the code.

Comment: @Fumu7 I am not sure what happened indeed. just a guess. but ok, i added my class code.

Comment: static variables an an ASP.NET application are likely a bad idea. Do you realize that they will be shared across all users of your application? Do you realize that multiple web requests, running at the same time, could try to access that data at the same time?

Comment: If you have a second question then please create a new question for it; don't use an existing question to ask a second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than a garbage collector issue (*as comments in your question have pointed out, and you should find Eric Lippert a good source anyway!*), it might be something with Internet Information Services application pool's recycling.

Default application pool settings will force a recycle after some idle time. Also, an application pool can go down if there's a fatal error (like a stack overflow) which can kill the IIS worker process. Other situation might be an extreme memory leak.

In summary:

- Go to your application's *application pool* settings and try to increase the idle time: (*NOTE: You shouldn't set this setting permantly: I'm suggesting this for debugging purposes in order to let you discover how application pool model works*).
- Add an `Application_Error` handler in your `Global.asax` and log exceptions there and see if something is going wrong after some time.

Comment: such such thank you. i have done the 2nd method but nothing threw. i will try the 1st way.

Comment: +1 "it might be ... application pool's recycling" - it almost certainly is.  But I don't agree with the recommendation to increase idle time.  Instead the app should expect that values in a static variable may be reset due to an AppDomain recycle, and regenerate them if this happens.

Comment: @Joe Well, it's not a recommendation. It's just for debugging purposes. OP needs to check what's going on, but I'll add a side note about this.